# Can we create a HQL query with same name but different Parameters?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Can we create a HQL query with same name but different Parameters,

and call it using `findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam()` method.

But the hibernate implementation of this metod is as follows.

```
public List findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(
        final String queryName, final String[] paramNames, final Object[] values)
        throws DataAccessException {

    if (paramNames != null && values != null && paramNames.length != values.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length of paramNames array must match length of values array");
    }
    return executeWithNativeSession(new HibernateCallback<List>() {
        public List doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
            Query queryObject = session.getNamedQuery(queryName);
            prepareQuery(queryObject);
            if (values != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    applyNamedParameterToQuery(queryObject, paramNames[i], values[i]);
                }
            }
            return queryObject.list();
        }
    });
}
```

So is it possible to create a HQL Query with same name but different parameters and call the query on the basis of Parameters dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot have multiple named queries with same name. You can write a dynamic query for this. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437053/jpa-where-clause-any/2439958#2439958) to see how to do this in HQL. Its showing how the Criteria API makes it simpler and is sounding better for your scenario. 
Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886587/abstracting-named-queries-in-an-abstract-jpa-dao) shows a unconventional way of doing something similar to your query.

Comment: @ali786 you are welcome sir.. did you get solution for the question?

Comment: Actually I have done by writing Dynamic Native Sql Query...:)

Comment: @ali786 that's good.. Could you please upload it as answer and accept your own answer.. Would be helpful for others